# How to register my android app to parse site

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How should i register my android app (or) device to parse push site to get the notification.
now i was connected to GCM.
am not able to step ahead and register my device with parse...

Comment: refer  https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-cloud-backend-android-app-using-parse/

Comment: then refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best way to implement official Parse SDK for standard push notification based on **my experiences** and **several trial and errors** and also **many SO and Parse threads reading**. So I'll walk you through these steps:

1. Add the following dependencies to the app build.gradle file, and you can get the latest versions from Parse github blank projects or Parse SDK from [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads) category in the website. the latest versions until now is here:

   ```
   compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
   compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
   ```
2. Add the following codes similar to the quick guide in the Application class's `onCreate()` method of the project, change the keys accordingly
   **-->** Take attention that these two lines must be added after `super.onCreate();` :

   ```
   // Enable Local Datastore.
   Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

   // Add your initialization code here
   Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR APPLICATION ID", "YOUR CLIENT KEY");
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

   ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
   ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
   // Optionally enable public read access.
   // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
   ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
   ```
3. Add the following line after `setContentView` in your MainActivity class:

   ```
   ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
   ```
4. add the Parse service and receivers to AndroidManifest.xml immediately before the closing `</application>` tag and make the mentioned package names identical to the yours:

   ```
   <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
   <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
       android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
       <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
       <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

       <!--
         IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
       -->
       <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
     </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
5. add permissions like the quick guide instructions typically immediately before the opening `<application>` tag, and make the mentioned package names identical to the yours, too:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

   <!--
     IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
     to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
   -->
   <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
       android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
   ```

**LAST STEP)** **Well Done! Enjoy pushing your stuff.** ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

 <permission
    android:name="${your_application_package}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="${your_application_package}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name="${your_application_package}.ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/contact_image"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Parse library -->
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
            <category android:name="${your_application_package}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Your ParseApplication should be like this

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //TODO: replace application_id and ClientKey with your parse credentials
        Parse.initialize(this, "application_id", "ClientKey");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Add the bolts-android-1.2.0 and Parse-1.9.2 libraries to your project. Now run the application and check in the parse dashborad you will find your device registered.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone...now am able to push notifications from parse to my app

Answer (score 0):

just i had downloaded a sample push application from parse site...and in that downloaded solution will have 2 projects ...1 for ios and 1 for android...ios wont push directly...so we need to make our android project as startup project and need to run our application...so that your phone will detect by your parse site and goto push tab in dashboard and select send push ...there in the textbox write what info you want to push and click on send now...so that push information will appear on your miobile